# how to install roots theme and wordpress as git submodule

Tags: wordpress, git, git-submodules

I am wordpress developer and want to use git in wordpress. I also want version control in my wordpress so that everything in the projects gets updated frequently.and also how to install wordpress as git submodule?
thanks,
suku

Comment: http://mattbanks.me/wordpress-deployments-with-git/ and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85731/wordpress-and-git-workflow should help here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add wordpress as a submodule from the root directory of your project like this:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git ./your/submodule/directory
```

Make sure that the directory doesn't exists before executing the above command.

I like to keep my root project directory nice and clean, and I use [Wordpress Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) in a directory called "app," while Wordpress sits in a directory called "wp," therefore I execute the command below from the root project directory.

```
git submodule add git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git ./app/wp/
```

This makes it really easy to update wordpress and keep everything under version control. To update to 3.8.1 do the following:

```
cd wp
git fetch && git fetch --tags
git checkout 3.8.1
cd ./
git add wp
git commit -m “Updated to WP 3.8.1”
git push
```

I wrote an unfinished article about it over here: http://www.kj-prince.com/wordpress-development-deployment/

Hope this helps.